# How do I send shell command in Espresso Test

Tags: android, ui-automation, android-espresso

I am new to Espresso. I want to test UI performance for an app(fluidity). I can create custom annotation in Espresso for getting fluidity for a particular test or automate new test cases. Does anyone know how to send command like "adb shell dumpsys gfxinfo app_package" from an espresso test?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a method [`android.app.UiAutomation#executeShellCommand`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/UiAutomation#executeShellCommand(java.lang.String)) added in Android 21.
And then just reading the result is needed with sth similar to what was implemented in the project [screenshot-tests-for-android](https://github.com/facebook/screenshot-tests-for-android): [implemented here](https://github.com/facebook/screenshot-tests-for-android/blob/master/core/src/main/java/com/facebook/testing/screenshot/internal/ScreenshotDirectories.java#L73)